# SwiftyJSONでnullが返ってきた時の対応の仕方を教えてください

Tags: swift, xcode, json, swift4

SwiftyJSONを使っています。

```
let request = Alamofire.request(url).response{
    response in
    var json = JSON.null;

    if response.error == nil && response.data != nil {
        json = try! SwiftyJSON.JSON(data: response.data!)
    }
    .......
}
```

と書いています。しかしnullが返されるapiにリクエストを出してもresponse.data != nilに反応せず、結果エラーが出てしまいます。
どうすればいいでしょうか。

Comment: 「nullが返されるapi」とは何を表しているのでしょうか?「応答全体がJSONのnullである」「応答の一部にJSONのnullが含まれている」「応答が空」等色々可能性が考えられます。また「response.data != nilに反応せず」と言うのは何を言いたいのでしょうか?「`json = try! SwiftyJSON.JSON(data: response.data!)`の行が必ず実行されてしまう」と言う意味ですか?また、「結果エラーが出てしまい」については、エラーの内容やどこでエラーになるかの情報もお示しいただいた方が良いでしょう。『どんな状況の時に』『何が起こり』『本当は何をしたいのか』をあなたのアプリやあなたのapiのことをよく知らない人間にも伝わるようにご質問内容を編集して、必要な情報を書き加えてみてください。

Comment: 解答ありがとうございます。
わかりにくい文章で大変申し訳ありませんでした。
nullが返ってくるとは、「応答全体がJSONのnullである」という意味でした。
apiは私の自作のapiなのですが、リクエストを送ると、JSONで返すときや、全体がnullの時もあります。
そして、今回、私が作りたいアプリは、応答がnullだった時でも、何も表示しないで先に進むようなアプリでした。
しかし応答がnullの時、どうしてもエラーが出て来てしまい、アプリが止まってしまいます。
私の認識ではresponse.data != nilでSwiftyJSONは使わなくても大丈夫だという認識なのですが、間違っていますでしょうか。

Comment: コメントへの返信ありがとうございます。「応答全体がJSONのnullである」場合には、HTTPレスポンスのボディ部分に`null`(0x6E 0x75 0x6C 0x6C)の4バイトが返ってきますので、`response.data`は決して`nil`にはなりません。ここまでの認識はよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: あと、繰り返しになりますが、「結果エラーが出てしまいます」に対する私のコメントに何も答えておられません。どの部分でどのようなエラーが出るのかきちんと記述をお願いします。